# Install latest Docker client through Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I have included these steps in my Dockerfile inorder to setup latest Docker client on my container

```
RUN wget -P /tmp/ https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-1.12.6.tgz && \
    tar -xvf /tmp/docker-1.12.6.tgz --directory /tmp/ && \
    mv /tmp/docker /usr/local/bin/docker
```

Want to make sure I got it right so I have entered into the container and did this

```
XX@XXXXXXXXXXXX:/$ docker
bash: docker: command not found
XX@XXXXXXXXXXXX:/$ docker version
bash: docker: command not found
XX@XXXXXXXXXXXX:/$
XX@XXXXXXXXXXXX:/$ which docker
XX@XXXXXXXXXXXX:/$
```

Not sure why that did not work. Please help!
Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: I would navigate to `/usr/local/bin` to check that the `docker` binary is there and the permissions are correct. Let me know how you went.

Comment: Need more information. What is the entire `Dockerfile`? What command used to run the container? What is the output of `env` inside the container shell? Sounds like `/usr/local/bin` probably isn't in `PATH`.

Comment: I just ended up putting the docker executable in my repo copying it into the container. get.docker.com have had trouble a couple of times causing headaches. (Same for images.. run local pull through cache / mirror so you're not screwed when docker hub dies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to copy the docker client binary to the `/usr/local/bin` rather than the entire uncompressed `docker` folder.
So the change should be: `mv /tmp/docker/docker /usr/local/bin`

Comment: Thanks so much :) @ichbinblau